# Laravel API with passport and Ldap Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, ldap, laravel-passport

I am trying to build an laravel api where users are authenticated with active directory. If authentication/login is successful, a token is generated for the user so that they can use it to access other resources. I am able to generate a token succesfully but I am unable to use the token to access a resource. Its throwing an error;

```
"message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Models\\User::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\\Users\\ENGINEER REX\\Desktop\\fleet_managment_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php on line 183 and exactly 1 expected",
    "exception": "ArgumentCountError",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\ENGINEER REX\\Desktop\\fleet_managment_api\\app\\Models\\User.php",
    "line": 69,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\ENGINEER REX\\Desktop\\fleet_managment_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php",
            "line": 183,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "App\\Models\\User",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\ENGINEER REX\\Desktop\\fleet_managment_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php",
            "line": 48,
            "function": "createModel",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\ENGINEER REX\\Desktop\\fleet_managment_api\\vendor\\adldap2\\adldap2-laravel\\src\\Auth\\DatabaseUserProvider.php",
            "line": 70,
            "function": "retrieveById",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

The Auth controller is as follows;

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\ADHelper;

use App\Http\Controllers\API\BaseController as BaseController;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Traits\Throttles;
use App\UserGroup;
use Exception;
use App\Exceptions\IncompleteADException;

class AuthenticationController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Register api
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;

        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User register successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Login api
     *  
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $result = ADHelper::authenticate($request->username, $request->password);
        if ($result->success) {
            $user = auth()->user();
            $user = new User($result->data);
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            $success['name'] =  $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;

            return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
            $this->setSessionStates($user, $request);

        } else {
            return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error' => 'Unauthorised']);
        }
    }
}
```

*// my config/auth.php

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

];

```
//My LDAP Helper File

    <?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class ADHelper
{
    /**
     * Authenticate user
     * @param $username
     * @param $password
     * @return  \App\Helper\HttpResponse
     */
    public static function authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        $provider = ADHelper::getADConnection($username, $password);
        if (!$provider) {
            return new HttpResponse(false, 'Invalid gn/password combination');
        }

        $user = $provider->search()->find($username);

        if (is_null($user)) return new HttpResponse(false, "Invalid gn/password combination");
        return new HttpResponse(true, $user);
    }

    /**
     * fetch all active directory users
     * @return \App\Helper\HttpResponse
     */
    public static function fetchADUsers()
    {
        try {
            $results = ADHelper::getADConnection()
                ->search()
                ->users()
                ->select(['mail', 'SAMAccountName', 'member', 'memberof', 'groups', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'manager'])
                ->where([
                    'objectClass' => 'user',
                    'objectCategory' => 'person',
                ])
                ->whereStartsWith('SAMAccountName', 'gn')
                ->whereContains('mail', '@zamtel')
                ->orFilter(function ($q) {
                    $q->whereStartsWith('mobile', '+26')
                        ->whereStartsWith('telephonenumber', '+26');
                })->get();

            return new HttpResponse(true, $results); // ['success' => true, 'data' => $results];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // return new HttpResponse(false, 'Unable to fetch results');
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * fetch manager
     * @return \App\Helper\HttpResponse
     */
    public static function getManager($distinguishedname) {
        try {
            $query = ADHelper::getADConnection()
                ->search()
                ->users()
                ->select(['cn', 'mail', 'SAMAccountName', 'memberof', 'member', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'manager'])
                ->where([
                    'objectClass' => 'user',
                    'objectCategory' => 'person',
                ])
                ->whereContains('mail', '@zamtel')
                ->where('distinguishedname', $distinguishedname);

            return $query->get()->first();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * search for users in Active Directory
     * @param string $search_term | needle
     * @return \App\Helper\HttpResponse
     */
   


       public static function search($search_term, $exact = false) {
         try {
             $query = ADHelper::getADConnection()
                 ->search()
                 ->users()
                 ->select(['cn', 'mail', 'SAMAccountName', 'memberof', 'member', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'manager'])
                 ->where([
                     'objectClass' => 'user',
                     'objectCategory' => 'person',
                 ])
                 ->whereStartsWith('SAMAccountName', 'gn')
                 ->whereContains('mail', '@zamtel')
                 ->orFilter(function ($q) {
                    $q->whereStartsWith('mobile', '+26')
                        ->whereStartsWith('telephonenumber', '+26');
                 });
             
             $query = ($exact)
                 ? $query->where('SAMAccountName', $search_term)
                 : $query->orFilter(function ($q) use ($search_term) {
                     $q->whereContains('cn', $search_term)
                        ->whereContains('SAMAccountName', $search_term);
                     });
             
             $results = $query->get();
             
             return new HttpResponse(true, $results); // ['success' => true, 'data' => $results];
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             // return new HttpResponse(false, 'Unable to fetch results');
             return ['success' => false, $e->getMessage(), 'message' => 'Unable to fetch results'];
         }
     }

     public static function searchByEmail($search_term) {
         try {
             $query = ADHelper::getADConnection()
                 ->search()
                 ->users()
                 ->select(['cn', 'mail', "memberof", 'SAMAccountName', 'member', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'manager'])
                 ->where([
                     'objectClass' => 'user',
                     'objectCategory' => 'person',
                 ])
                 ->whereContains('mail', '@zamtel')
                 ->orFilter(function ($q) use ($search_term) {
                    $q->whereContains('mobile', $search_term)
                        ->whereContains('telephonenumber', $search_term)
                        ->whereContains('mail', $search_term);

                        
                 });
             
             $results = $query->get();
             
             return new HttpResponse(true, $results); // ['success' => true, 'data' => $results];
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             // return new HttpResponse(false, 'Unable to fetch results');
             return ['success' => false, $e->getMessage(), 'message' => 'Unable to fetch results'];
         }
    }




    public static function searchByGN($search_term) {
        try {
            $query = ADHelper::getADConnection()
                ->search()
                ->users()
                ->select(['cn', 'mail', "memberof", 'SAMAccountName', 'member', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'manager'])
                ->where([
                    'objectClass' => 'user',
                    'objectCategory' => 'person',
                ])
                ->whereContains('mail', '@zamtel')
                ->orFilter(function ($q) use ($search_term) {
                   $q->whereContains('mobile', $search_term)
                       ->whereContains('telephonenumber', $search_term)
                       ->whereContains('mail', $search_term)
                       ->whereContains('SAMAccountName', $search_term);

                       
                });
            
            $results = $query->get();
            
            return new HttpResponse(true, $results); // ['success' => true, 'data' => $results];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // return new HttpResponse(false, 'Unable to fetch results');
            return ['success' => false, $e->getMessage(), 'message' => 'Unable to fetch results'];
        }
   }

    /**
     * search for users in Active Directory
     * @param string $search_term | user GN
     * @return \App\User | null
     */
    public static function findUserByGN($gn)
    {
        $result = ADHelper::search($gn, true);

        return ($result->success && $result->data->count() == 1)
            ? new \App\User($result->data->first())
            : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the active LDAP Connection.
     *
     * @return bool|ConnectionInterface
     */
    public static function getADConnection($username = null, $password = null, $group = null, $OU = null)
    {
        if (is_null($username) && is_null($password)) {
            $OU = is_null($OU) ? '' : "ou=$OU,";
            $username = \config('ad.ad_user');
            $password = \config('ad.ad_password');
            $base_dn = "${OU}ou=Zamtel,dc=zamtel,dc=co,dc=zm"; //"CN={$group},OU={$OU},OU=Zamtel,DC=zamtel,DC=co,DC=zm";
        } else {
            $base_dn = 'dc=zamtel,dc=co,dc=zm';
        }

        $ad = new \Adldap\Adldap();
        $config = [
            'hosts' => [\config('ad.ad_host')],
            'base_dn' => $base_dn,
            'username' => "zamtel\\$username",
            'password' => $password,
        ];

        $ad->addProvider($config);

        try {
            return $ad->connect();
            // return $ad->getLdapConnection();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function getListofManager()
    {
        return ADHelper::getList('DL-Managers', 'Human Resource');
    }

    public static function getListofSupervisors()
    {
        return ADHelper::getList('DL-Supervisors', 'Human Resource');
    }

    public static function getListofChiefs()
    {
        return ADHelper::getList('DL-EXMA', 'EXCO');
    }

    public static function getDrivers()
    {
        return ADHelper::getList('DL-Drivers');
    }

    public static function getFleetCoordinators() {
        $result = ADHelper::getList("DL-Fleetcoordinator");

            return $result;
        }

       

    public static function getFleetManager()
    {
        return ADHelper::getList("DL-Fleetmanager");
    }

    

    public static function getList($groupName)
    {
        try {
            $conn = ADHelper::getADConnection();

            $group = $conn->search()->groups()->find($groupName);
            $members = $group->getMembers();


            //dd( $members);
            $result = [];

            foreach($members as $m) {

                $result[] = new \App\User($m);

            }


            
            return new HttpResponse(true, $result);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
//Routes

<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthenticationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\RequisitionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\VehicleVerificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\HomeController;





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('register', [AuthenticationController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [AuthenticationController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('getCurrentUser',[HomeController::class, 'getCurrentUser']);
Route::get('getToken', [AuthenticationController::class, 'getToken']);

// Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// });

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('requisitions', RequisitionController::class);
    Route::resource('checkoutForm', VehicleVerificationController::class);
    // Route::get('current_user', HomeController::class);
    
});


//Users.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Helpers\ADHelper;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, HasFactory;

     // public $objectclass; //array(String)
     public $gn; // string samaccountname
     public $fullname; // string cn
     public $firstname; // string givenname
     public $surname; // string sn
     public $location; // string l
     public $station; // string s
     public $title; // string
     public $description; // array/(String)
     public $telephonenumber; // string
     public $mobile; // string
     public $phone; // string
     public $distinguishedname; // string
     public $memberof; // string
     public $groups; // array
     public $mail; // string
     public $is_admin = false; // boolean
     public $is_contributor = false; // boolean
     public $unauthorized = true; // boolean
     public $is_guest = false; // boolean
     public $permission_id; // integer
     public $manager; // string
    

    protected $fillable = ['first_name',
                           'last_name', 
                           'username', 
                           'email', 
                           'phone_number',
                            'password', 
                            'user_group_id', 
                            'supervisor_id', 
                            'manager_id', 
                            'fleet_manager_id', 
                            'ministry_id', 
                            'remember_token', 
                            'created_at', 
                            'updated_at'];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function __construct($obj)
    {

        $memberof = is_array($obj->memberof) ? $obj->memberof : [];

        $manager = !is_null($obj->manager) ? $obj->manager[0] : "";
        

        $this->gn = !is_null($obj->samaccountname) ? $obj->samaccountname[0] : null;
        $this->fullname = !is_null($obj->cn) ? $obj->cn[0] : null;
        $this->firstname = !is_null($obj->givenname) ? $obj->givenname[0] : null;
        $this->surname = !is_null($obj->sn) ? $obj->sn[0] : null;
        $this->location = !is_null($obj->physicaldeliveryofficename) ? $obj->physicaldeliveryofficename[0] : null;
        $this->station = !is_null($obj->station) ? $obj->station[0] : null;
        $this->title = !is_null($obj->title) ? $obj->title[0] : null;
        $this->description = !is_null($obj->description) ? $obj->description[0] : null;
        $this->telephonenumber = \preg_replace('/ /', '', !is_null($obj->telephonenumber) ? $obj->telephonenumber[0] : '');
        $this->mobile = preg_replace('/ /', '', !is_null($obj->mobile) ? $obj->mobile[0] : '');
        $this->distinguishedname = !is_null($obj->distinguishedname) ? $obj->distinguishedname[0] : null;
        $this->mail = !is_null($obj->mail) ? $obj->mail[0] : null;
        $this->memberof = \implode(',', $memberof);
        $this->groups = $memberof;
        $this->phone = !is_null($this->telephonenumber) ? $this->telephonenumber : $this->mobile;
        $this->manager =  $this->getManager($manager);
    }



    public function getManager($dn) {

        try {
             $obj = ADHelper::getManager($dn);
              
             $memberof = is_array($obj->memberof) ? $obj->memberof : [];
             $telephonenumber = \preg_replace('/ /', '', !is_null($obj->telephonenumber) ? $obj->telephonenumber[0] : '');
             $mobile = preg_replace('/ /', '', !is_null($obj->mobile) ? $obj->mobile[0] : '');
 
             return  (object)[
                         "gn" => !is_null($obj->samaccountname) ? $obj->samaccountname[0] : null,
                         "fullname" => !is_null($obj->cn) ? $obj->cn[0] : null,
                         "firstname" => !is_null($obj->givenname) ? $obj->givenname[0] : null,
                         "surname" => !is_null($obj->sn) ? $obj->sn[0] : null,
                         "location" => !is_null($obj->physicaldeliveryofficename) ? $obj->physicaldeliveryofficename[0] : null,
                         "station" => !is_null($obj->station) ? $obj->station[0] : null,
                         "title" => !is_null($obj->title) ? $obj->title[0] : null,
                         "description" => !is_null($obj->description) ? $obj->description[0] : null,
                         "telephonenumber" => $telephonenumber,
                         "mobile" => $mobile,
                         "distinguishedname" => !is_null($obj->distinguishedname) ? $obj->distinguishedname[0] : null,
                         "mail" => !is_null($obj->mail) ? $obj->mail[0] : null,
                         "memberof" => implode(',', $memberof),
                         "groups" => $memberof,
                         "phone" => !is_null($telephonenumber) ? $telephonenumber : $mobile
                     ];
 
        } catch (\Exception $e){
             return NULL;
        }
     }
 
 
 
     public  function isManager() : bool {
         $title = !is_null($this->title) ? $this->title : $this->description;
         return preg_match("/DL-(Manager|Supervisor)/i", $this->memberof) || preg_match("/team lead/i", $title);
     }
 
 
     public  function isFleetManager() : bool {
        
         return preg_match("/FleetManager/i", $this->memberof);
     }
 
  
     public  function isFleetCoordinator() : bool {
         return preg_match("/Fleetcoordinator/i", $this->memberof);
     }
 
     public  function isDriver() : bool{
         return preg_match("/Drivers/i", $this->memberof);
     }
 
     public  function isFleetSupervisor() : bool{
         return preg_match("/FleetSupervisor/i", $this->memberof);
     }
 

}
```

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRCIATED HIGHLY...

Comment: share your User.php (Model File)

Comment: Add in your question

Comment: @dev_mustafa i have added the model..(users.php)

Comment: what are you passing in your User construct? Try removing $obj and it should work.

Comment: @dev_mustafa if I remove it, its giving undefined variable "obj"

Comment: Why you have added $obj in construct?

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes I managed to solve it.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @ThulaniRex What wa the solution???